# Using AOP for Exception Handling in Serenity project for API testing

Tags: java, maven, exception, aop, serenity-bdd

I am fairly new to AOP, but I am trying to use it for exception handling in a Serenity project that is used to test an API. I essentially want to return the last API response when a key in the API response body is not found (which currently throws an exception).

I am currently converting the responses to a `JSONObject` and have tried directing my pointcut to the `get(String)` method within that class. However the aspect never seems to catch the exception. My understanding is that Spring AOP can only add an aspect to objects created by the Spring factory. Whether or not the `JSONObject` class qualifies (it comes from an external library), I am unsure. Therefore I've tried only using AspectJ, but to no avail. My second approach was to direct my pointcut (using Spring AOP) to the class where my step definitions are defined, and from where the `JSONObject.get(String)` is called. The class contains the `@Component` annotation and is managed by the Spring factory. Yet again, the exception is not caught. Below is my aspect class with the different approaches I've attempted.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExceptionHandlerAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(Object org.json.JSONObject.get(String))")
    public void steps(){}

    @Around("steps()")
    public Object handleException(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed(joinPoint.getArgs());
        } catch (JSONException w) {
            System.out.println("The JSONException was caught by the handler " + w);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* myapp.testing.step_definitions.OrderSteps.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    private void handleException(JSONException ex) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("The exception was caught by the handler " + ex);
    }
}
```

FWIW I've tried both `@Around` and `@AfterThrowing` approaches while directing my pointcut to the `JSONObject` class and my `OrderSteps` class. Below is a snippet of my step definition class.

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Application.class}, initializers=ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
public class OrderSteps {

    @Autowried
    private OrderService orderService

    private final SoftAssertions assertions = new SoftAssertions();

    @Then("^The order should be submitted$")
    public void theOrderShouldBeSubmitted() throws Throwable {
        JSONObject response = orderService.getOrderApiResponse();
        assertions.assertThat(response.getString("test").isEqualTo("Submit");
        assertions.assertAll();
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myapp.testing</groupId>
<artifactId>api-integration</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <serenity.version>1.2.2</serenity.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.23</serenity.cucumber.version>
    <surefire.version>2.19.1</surefire.version>
    <compiler.version>3.5</compiler.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <selenium.version>3.0.1</selenium.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    <assertj.version>3.5.2</assertj.version>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${compiler.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire.version}</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>${surefire.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                </includes>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>cucumber-tests</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.serenity-bdd.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>serenity-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${serenity.version}</version>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
                    <version>${serenity.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>serenity-reports</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>aggregate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20160810</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
        <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-core</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>serenity-rest-assured</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>${serenity.version}</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-cucumber</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.serenity-bdd</groupId>
        <artifactId>serenity-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${serenity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
        <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>-->
        <!--<groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>-->
        <!--<artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>-->
        <!--<version>1.8.10</version>-->
    <!--</dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
            <version>Brussels-SR1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Any tips or advice are greatly appreciated!

Comment: From my understanding Spring AOP requires the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotation on the class that contains the `@Configuration` annotation. However I am using `@EnableAutoConfiguration` so I'm unsure exactly where `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` should go.